# How to use a component depending on the route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

Hello I am currently doing the front end of my project.

I would like to render components dynamically depending on the route.
For example I have a /auth route then it links to /auth/login or /auth/register or /auth/forgot.

This is the place where I would like to see the different components rendered.
I was assuming I can use router-view to loud the different components into the DOM.

```
<template>
<head-comp></head-comp>
<router-view></router-view>
<footer-comp></footer-comp>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderComp from '../components/Universal/HeaderComp.vue'
import FooterComp from '../components/Universal/FooterComp.vue'
export default
{
  components: {
    'header-comp' : HeaderComp,
    'footer-comp' : FooterComp
  }
}

</script>
```

This is the router

```
    {
      path: '/auth',
      name: 'auth',
      component: () => import('../views/AuthView.vue'),
      children: [
        { 
        path: 'login',
        name: 'auth.login',
        component: () => import('../components/Authentication/LoginComp.vue') 
      },
      ],
    }
```

And this is the vue file that will contain the login form.

```
<tempalte>
Login
</tempalte>

<script>

</script>
```

The error I get with my current approach is this.

```
The requested module '/src/components/Authentication/LoginComp.vue?vue&type=tempalte&index=0&lang.tempalte' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I was thinking I could just use different views for example, login/registerView.vue instead of having them in components but I feel like this is messier and would make it harder to maintain in the future.

Thanks for reading and looking forward to your responses.

Comment: Are you wrapping your `export default` in the first code block with an additional set of curly braces? The JS engine may not like an anonymous export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in your LoginComp.vue component.

```
<tempalte>
Login
</tempalte>
```

should be

```
<template>
Login
</template>
```

Comment: ... I can not believe it even with minimal boiler plate I still made a typo... I thought my intelisense completed it for me... thank you sir